# How significant is the discount for each of the shops compared to the ship?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Cortez mentions that you get higher prices by shopping through him due to shipping (I'd hate to see the shipping cost across a couple of relays in wartime).

My question is simple:  How significant are the discounts for each shop in the game and where are the original shops located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alliance Requisition terminal allows you to purchase items at 110% their price.
Most shops are located in the Presidium Commons. The two exceptions are the Batarian arms shop, at the temporary refugee housing on Citadel, and Sirta, located at the hospital's entrance.

Comment: So the 110% is just a blanket upscale?  Figure it would get higher the further you got, but i suppose the higher cost of items makes up for that